# Nested 'ifelse'-statement for quantiles

Tags: r, if-statement

I am attempting to assign a number from 1 through 10 to a series of vectors based on what quantile they're in in a dataframe.

So far I have tried

```
quants <- quantile(Data$Avg, c(.1, .2, .3, .4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9)) 

Data$quant <- for ( i in nrow(Data) ) {
  ifelse(Data$Avg [i] < quants[1], Data$quant[1] = 1 , 
         ifelse(Data$Avg [i] > quants[1] & Data$Avg[i] < quants[2], Data$quant[1] = 2, Data$quant = 3
                   ))}
```

I get the following mistake:

[image]

Can anyone spot the mistake I am making here?

Comment: Try using a regular if statement instead of `ifelse`

Comment: There are a bunch of syntax errors. For example, `Data$quant[1] = 1` should be `1`, and using a `for` loop is unnecessary. I would look into using `cut` or `findInterval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be better off using `cut` rather than a loop:

```
Data = data.frame(Avg = runif(100))
quantpoints <- seq(0.1, 0.9, 0.1)
quants <- quantile(Data$Avg, quantpoints)

cutpoints <- c(-Inf, quants, Inf)

cut(Data$Avg, breaks = cutpoints, labels = seq(1, length(cutpoints) - 1))
```

Comment: Fantastic. Very nice solution, which I didn't know about. Thanks so much. I just added `Data$quant <- cut(Data$Avg, breaks = cutpoints, labels = seq(1, length(cutpoints) - 1))` to assign the values to the vector as I requested above

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
Data$quant <- for ( i in nrow(Data) ) {
  Data$quant[1] <- ifelse(Data$Avg [i] < quants[1],  1, ifelse(Data$Avg [i] > quants[1] & Data$Avg[i] < quants[2], 2, 3))
}
```

Or equivalently (inside the `for` loop):

```
if(Data$Avg [i] < quants[1])
    Data$quant[1] <- 1
else{
    if(Data$Avg [i] > quants[1] & Data$Avg[i] < quants[2])
        Data$quant[1] <- 2
    else
        Data$quant[1] <- 3
}
```

You should assign the output of `ifelse` conditions outside of it. That is:

```
output <- ifelse(a > b, a, b)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. I have tried to attempt the first solution. However, I get pure 3's in Data$Quant, even though the following test `> Data$Avg[26]<quants[1]` is "TRUE"

Comment: @pApaAPPApapapa without having data, its difficult to find out the problem. You might want to `dput` your data in order for me to test it.

Comment: @pApaAPPApapapa If its logic does not work as expected, there is something in your data, I'd say or your algorithmic logic.